# 404 when calling Jersey 2 REST endpoint on Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey

This is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Simulator HTTP API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Simulator HTTP API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my simple web service:

```
@Path("partner")
public class PartnerAPI {

    @Path("/mt")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sendMT() {
        return "Sent";
    }

}
```

when i call it like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/partner/mt
```

i get 404 error mot found, what am i doing wrong?

#### Update

this is my maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have a class extending `ResourceConfig`?

Comment: @unwichtich no, i just have a class (not extend anything) and has one method, that i showed to u

Comment: @unwichtich help plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different deployment options in Jersey 2:

If you want to do it via `web.xml` you have to add the an `init-param` where you specify which packages should be scanned:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Simulator HTTP API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>insert.packagename.where.your.class.is.here</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Another option is to create a basic class to configure your REST application.

This would look like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

    @ApplicationPath("/test")
    public class YourApplication extends ResourceConfig {
        public YourApplication() {
            this.packages("insert.packagename.where.your.class.is.here");
        }
    }
```

Make sure to update the string with the package name where your `PartnerAPI` class is.

Then add the value inside `@ApplicationPath` to your URL. 
The link would look like this: http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/test/partner/mt

More information: [Jersey docs: Chapter 4. Deploying a RESTful Web Service](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/2.0/deployment.html)

Comment: are you saying to also delete the web.xml ?

Comment: plus, where should I put this `YourApplication` class? in the same package with `PartnerAPI` class ?

Comment: You can delete the web.xml if you want. It shouldn't matter if the class is in the same package. It is only required that the class is in the same project.

Comment: thanks, could you help me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174590/glass-fish-java-can-i-send-object-through-get-request

Comment: This class isn't needed with the web.xml. Personally I prefer using the ResourceConfig, but what the OP was really missing was the init-param for the package(s) to scan. See example 4.7 in the link from your answer.