# glass fish java can i send object through get request?

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I have a class like this:

```
class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and I have a glass fish web service:

i want to know it is possible to send a customer object using **get**

(i know i can do this in post, but in get ... i don't know)

this is what i tried:

```
@GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public String test(@QueryParam("customer") Customer customer) {
        return "Done " + customer.getId();
    }
```

then i call it like this:

```
..../test?id=4&name=william
```

I know that is wrong, but i don't know the correct way, and i don't know if that is even possible using get

Comment: Should `name` be `customer`

Comment: @DavidPulse i don't think so because customer is an object, that is what i am asking for actually

Comment: Please read something about the basics of REST...what do you expect from sending an java object via HTTP...what do you think the "downloader" will receive?

Comment: Well, I was looking at QueryPararm. So, why do you name a variable after the class, and how's it supposed to know the `name` when you haven't a method that gives any real information?

Comment: @unwichtich this is possible sweetheart if the method is post and the data in the request is json. i am asking about get, please don't make fun. your respect to other people reflects your respect to yourself

Comment: one way is to serialize the Customer object in json and set the json string as a query param in the URL (something like `?customer={name:blahblah}`). but the test method should have a string parameter and then you should deserialize the string in the final object.

Comment: Se what max said? You'r4 querying for customer as a urlParam. It only has id and name

Comment: You're trying to fit a square block in a round hole. It'll be a `customer`, but you!re querying the type, not the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@QueryParam` should be used for each individual parameter. For instance

```
/cusomters?name=hello&id=1

@GET
@Produces(...)
public Response get(@QueryParam("name") String name,
                    @QueryParam("id") int id)
```

If you want put it into a bean, you can use [`@BeanParam`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html), which allows you to put arbitrary `@XxxParam`s into a bean. For example

```
class Customer {
    @QueryParam("name")
    private String name;
    @QueryParam("id")
    private int id;
    // getters/setters
}

@GET
public Response get(@BeanParam Customer customer)
```

But do keep in mind REST principles. To create a customer resource, it *should* be done with POST. Also be considerate of security concerns. You do not want private user information in URLs.

Comment: what is the @consum annotation in this case ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli You don't use `@Consumes` for GET. There is no body. `@Consumes` is only to say the type of entity body you can handle (whch is mainly for POST/PUT). Since there is no body, no need for the annotation. All your data is coming in the URL not the body

Comment: I am trying to make it work, please could you tel me how to return this response with status 200 and with body "sent" ?

Comment: `return Response.ok("sent").build()`. You can just return a String and it will automatically return a 200. You don't _have_ to use `Response`. It's something I prefer to do though

Comment: one thing please , i did this in the method  `System.out.println(mt.getCP_Id());` and i call it like this `sendMT2?cP_Id=asdf` but i get the result printed as null. could you help, i did exactly what you said