# rest service url not working (404) -Glassfish

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I have  created a simple restful web service based on some examples and built it into a .war file(project structure has web.xml under WEB-INF), deploy it on glassfish ang get a 404 not found error when i try to call it.
My class containing the service is :

```
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

/**
 * Created by Nikos Kritikos on 10/22/2015.
 */

@Path("/decks")
public class HS_Services {

    @Path("sayHello/{name}")
    @GET
    public String doSayHello(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return "Hello there "+name;
    }

}
```

my web.xml is this :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HSRestServices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HSRestServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hsrest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

i try to call it with http://localhost:8080/HSRestServices/hsrest/decks/sayHello/Nikos but i get 404 from glassfish..
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why /HSRestServices in URL?

Comment: Add `@Controller` to your `HS_Services` class to tell Spring that is web controller

Comment: because HSRestServices is the servlet's name, and the web application name.I tested  http://localhost:8080/hsrest/decks/sayHello/Nikos , didnt work

Comment: Valijon, i dont use spring, why need this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `init-param` where you specify which packages should be scanned for REST endpoint classes.

Change your `web.xml` to look like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>HSRestServices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>insert.packagename.where.your.class.is.here</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Make sure to insert the name of the package which contains your class.

You don't need Spring for this.

There is also another way which works without `web.xml`. For details have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173904/404-when-calling-jersey-2-rest-endpoint-on-glassfish).